# How can I use setOnClickListener in my adapter Android?

Tags: android

In my aplication I have ListView and adapter to my ListView. My item ListView have two elements Text and Image. Now I want to separate the text and click on the picture.

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private Activity context;
private ArrayList<String> categories;
public static boolean remove = true;

public MyAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<String> categories) {
    super(context, R.layout.my_list_element, categories);
    this.context = context;
    this.categories = categories;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView tvLanguage;
    public ImageView remove;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView = convertView;
    if (rowView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_list_element, null);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.tvLanguage = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvLanguage);
        viewHolder.remove = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.remove);
        rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
    holder.tvLanguage.setText(categories.get(position));
    if(remove)
        holder.remove.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    else
        holder.remove.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    return rowView;
}
```

How i should separate text and image and success use setOnClickListener on two elements ?

Answer (score 4):

modify the first block to be like this:

```
if (rowView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_list_element, null);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.tvLanguage = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvLanguage);
        viewHolder.remove = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.remove);
        rowView.setTag(viewHolder);

        viewHolder.tvLanguage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(View v){  
              // handle your text view  
           }
        });

        viewHolder.remove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(View v){    
              // handle your imageview
           }
        });

}
```

Comment: Thanks but when I paste my code to switch activity it's doesn't work ? Some tips ?

Comment: can't understand you..are you saying that onClick is never called..do you switch your activity inside the onClick event?

Comment: Pasted my code instead of / / handle your ImageView and this is my code: Intent i = new Intent (this, AddRSS.class);
     startActivity (j);

Comment: you are declaring intent i then start activity using intent j

Comment: yes I mistake, but I change this and still it's doesn't work. I dont know how I can open new activity when I click on my remove ImageView

Comment: just make sure that onClick is fired, put a log inside the function or show a toast, is there any error while starting AddRSS activity?

Comment: I paste in my onClick Log.v("Message", "message"); and my log cat show this. So it is OK, but I still cant switch activity. Eclipse highlights in red startActivity (i);

Answer (score 0):

Try to add flags to your intent
like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent (this, AddRSS.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(i);
```

The code above will start an activity and it will become the start of a new task on the history stack.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem :) I can't use this code

```
Intent i = new Intent (this, AddRSS.class); 
startActivity (i);
```

because my class MyAdapter does not extend Activity so I could not use a method startActivity(i);

The solution is simple, I use context :

```
Intent i = new Intent (context, AddRSS.class); 
context.startActivity (i);
```

and now works ;)